# la función int simpleArraySum deberia sumar, pero creo que me falta completarla, que más le pondrían?

Tags: c

```
 #include <assert.h>
 #include <limits.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <stdbool.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

   char* readline();
   char** split_string(char*);

  /*
   * Complete the simpleArraySum function below.
   */
int simpleArraySum(int ar_count, int* ar) {
int  sum=0;
int ar[ar_count];

for (int ar_itr = 0; ar_itr < ar_count; ar_itr++) {
 sum=sum+ar[ar-count];
printf("%d",sum);
}

}

int main()
{
FILE* fptr = fopen(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"), "w");

char* ar_count_endptr;
char* ar_count_str = readline();
int ar_count = strtol(ar_count_str, &ar_count_endptr, 10);

if (ar_count_endptr == ar_count_str || *ar_count_endptr != '\0') { 
exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

char** ar_temp = split_string(readline());

int ar[ar_count];

for (int ar_itr = 0; ar_itr < ar_count; ar_itr++) {
    char* ar_item_endptr;
    char* ar_item_str = ar_temp[ar_itr];
    int ar_item = strtol(ar_item_str, &ar_item_endptr, 10);

    if (ar_item_endptr == ar_item_str || *ar_item_endptr != '\0') { 
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    ar[ar_itr] = ar_item;
}

int result = simpleArraySum(ar_count, ar);

fprintf(fptr, "%d\n", result);

fclose(fptr);

return 0;
  }

  char* readline() {
  size_t alloc_length = 1024;
  size_t data_length = 0;
      char* data = malloc(alloc_length);

     while (true) {
    char* cursor = data + data_length;
    char* line = fgets(cursor, alloc_length - data_length, stdin);

    if (!line) { break; }

    data_length += strlen(cursor);

    if (data_length < alloc_length - 1 || data[data_length - 1] == '\n') { 
    break; }

    size_t new_length = alloc_length << 1;
    data = realloc(data, new_length);

    if (!data) { break; }

    alloc_length = new_length;
}

if (data[data_length - 1] == '\n') {
    data[data_length - 1] = '\0';
}

data = realloc(data, data_length);

return data;
}

char** split_string(char* str) {
char** splits = NULL;
char* token = strtok(str, " ");

int spaces = 0;

while (token) {
    splits = realloc(splits, sizeof(char*) * ++spaces);
    if (!splits) {
        return splits;
    }

    splits[spaces - 1] = token;

    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}

return splits;
}
```

Comment: Hola, para mejorar el formato de tu pregunta y así aumentar las posibilidades de poder ayudarte, te recomiendo que revises la página de ayuda sobre [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Qué es lo que estás tratando de resolver?, en definitiva qué es lo que debe hacer esa función? Saludos!!

Comment: Esto tiene toda la pinta de un ejercicio (por los comentarios) en el que no has hecho nada. ¿ Cómo puedes 'creer que no está completa'  ? ¿ No sabes lo que hace ? ¿ No sabes lo que debería hacer ?

Comment: si , ya complete la función , no sé qué me falta

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *no sé qué me falta*?, ¿por qué dices eso? ¿conceptualmente qué te falta?, una cosa que observo es que `simpleArraySum` no retorna nada, asi que pienso que eso te falta: `int simpleArraySum(int ar_count, int* ar) {
int  sum=0;
for (int ar_itr = 0; ar_itr < ar_count; ar_itr++) {
 sum=sum+ar[ar-count];} return sum;}`